# Aligned column text with the title of the section

Tags: indentation, columns

In the following MWE [adopted from here and modified](https://texblog.org/2012/04/25/writing-a-cv-in-latex/) how is it possible to have each entry aligned with the name of the section, that is, without indent? Also I want each entry to span the whole text width.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\title{\bfseries\Huge Tom T. Texblog}
\author{texblog+cv@gmail.com}
\date{}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.85\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Main Road 25\\
City 12345\\
State of Sabotage
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Nonlandian\\
January 3rd, 2020\\
+12 34 56 789
\end{minipage}
\vspace{20pt}

\section*{Objective}
\lipsum[33]

\section*{Professional Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2011--today&{\bf Work at company XY.}\\
&\lipsum[66]\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2005--2007&{\bf MSc in Computer Science, Great University, Country.}\\[5pt]
2001--2005&BSc in Life Science, Great University, Country.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Languages}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
Klingon&Mother tongue\\
{\bf English}&{\bf Fluent}\\
French&Fluent (DELF 2010)\\
Japanese&Fair\\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the vertical lines to be at the same horizontal position for all the tables regardless of the width of the first column? Should the entries in the first column be right of left aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it would only make sense to align first column at Left, I have presumed that's what you need, the simplest way for me to over-ride the indent is add a -9pt space prior to each tabular environment, then simply adjust the column textwidth proportions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, lipsum, bibentry}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\title{\bfseries\Huge Tom T. Texblog}
\author{texblog+cv@gmail.com}
\date{}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright}p{0.09\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.89\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Main Road 25\\
City 12345\\
State of Sabotage
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
Nonlandian\\
January 3rd, 2020\\
+12 34 56 789
\end{minipage}
\vspace{20pt}

\section*{Objective}
\lipsum[33]

\section*{Professional Experience}
\hspace{-9pt} \begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
 2011--today&{\bf Work at company XY.}\\
&\lipsum[66]\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Education}
\hspace{-9pt} \begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
2005--2007&{\bf MSc in Computer Science, Great University, Country.}\\[5pt]
2001--2005&BSc in Life Science, Great University, Country.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Languages}
\hspace{-9pt} \begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
Klingon&Mother tongue\\
{\bf English}&{\bf Fluent}\\
French&Fluent (DELF 2010)\\
Japanese&Fair\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```