# Align the left margin of a tabular environment with the left margin of the paragraph

Tags: horizontal-alignment, leftmargin

There seems to be a small left indent to a tabular enviroment, which offsets the left margin of the tabular (first column) from the left margin of the enclosing paragraph.

I would like to know how to supress this indent.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test}
\noindent
Some text

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ll}
        abc \\
        cbd
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

I did see this earlier question: [Aligned column text with the title of the section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489586/aligned-column-text-with-the-title-of-the-section/490028#490028), which works (replace `\begin{tabular}{ll}` with `\hspace{-6pt}\begin{tabular}{ll}` in my example) but I need to iteratively tailor the negative hspace value (e.g., I seem to need -6pt, whereas the answer states -9pt).

Is there a more general adjustment I can make?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `tabular` environment enforces some default separation spacing between columns. You can suppress the separator between two columns (or before the first column and after the last) by suitably adding an `@{}` in the column specification argument.
More generally, whatever (even nonempty) argument you provide to `@` will be used as column separator.
Note that the same syntax works for math `array` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test}
\noindent
Some text

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll} % <--- added @{} before the first column
        abc \\
        cbd
\end{tabular}

\noindent
You can also put a nonempty argument:

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{: }l}
    Apple & fruit \\
    Cabbage & vegetable
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you that does the trick :-)